# How to set On back option for Navigation and Current activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, navigation

I have a created a app with List view when i click back button from home page it will toast a message and ask to exit or not. after i have implement a Navigation drawer and set open and close. but when i click back button from navigation go back and popup the toast which i set to hoe page.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    AdminHome.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

how to stop the toast message when i click back from navigation bar and set toast from home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi You can change your code like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}else{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                AdminHome.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        })

        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Put the AlertDialog code in else block.

Answer (score 0):

Put your alertdialog inside `else` of your condition

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

           AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
           alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```